# Stretch navigation bar of images across page?

Tags: html, css

I am sure this has been asked before so I apologize but I cant find an answer that works for me - or perhaps I just don't understand.

I am new in HTML & CSS and I am trying to build a navigation bar of images that stretches to 100% of the width of the screen. It would be great if someone could show me what I am missing. The links are going to be changed later.

```
<body>
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">
             <img src="images/logo.png" height="80" width="150">
        </a>
    </li>
    <div id="menu">
        <li>
             <a href="index.html">
                   <img src="images/homeButton.png" height="80" width="150"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
              <a href="index.html">
                   <img src="images/scratchButton.png" height="80" width="150">
              </a>
        </li>
        <li>
              <a href="index.html">
                   <img src="images/c++Button.png" height="80" width="150">
              </a>
        </li>
        <li>
             <a href="index.html"> 
                   <img src="images/PythonButton.png" height="80" width="150">
             </a>
        </li>
        <li>
             <a href="index.html">
                   <img src="images/signInButton.png" height="80" width="150">
             </a>
        </li>
    </div>
</ul>
```

.

```
html, body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0
}

li {
float: left;
}

a {

}

#menu {
width: 100%;
list-style-type: none;
background-color: #000000;
}

#menu :hover{
background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a table and specify the columns as equal widths and place it in a div which occupies 100% of the width.

E.g.:

```
<div id="container">
<table>
<col width="20%">
<col width="20%">
<col width="20%">
<col width="20%">
<col width="20%"> // maybe you can make all five statements at once
<tr>
<td>1st/td>
<td>2nd</td>
<td>3rd</td>
<td>4th</td>
<td>5th</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

And